# Data structure to represent multiple equivalent keys in set in Python?

Tags: python, data-structures, set

Currently, I want to find the correct data structure to meet the following requirement.

There are multiple arrays with disordered element, for example,

`[1, 2], [2, 1], [3, 2, 2], [2], [2, 1, 3], [2, 2, 3]`

After processing those data, the result is,

`[1, 2], [2, 2, 3], [2], [1, 2, 3]`

With sorted element in each array and filter the duplicate arrays.

Here are my thoughts:

- Data structure `Set(Arrays)`? - Failed. It seems there is only one array in the build-in `set`

  `set([])`
- Data structure `Array(Sets)`? - Failed. However, there is no duplicate element in the build-in `set`. **I want to know whether there is one data structure like [`multiset`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/multiset/) in C++ within Python?**

Comment: BTW, those look like normal Python lists, not Python [arrays](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html)s; the popular 3rd-party package Numpy also provides [array](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.creation.html) types.

Comment: map(list,set(tuple(sorted(i)) for i in a)), if a is the input

Comment: @Vineesh: Please don't put answers into comments.

Comment: To answer your question: I think that `list` **is** your multiset ...

Comment: @haavee: Good call; OTOH, unlike a "proper" multiset `list` preserves ordering, and it doesn't provide a simple intersection method. Also, testing for membership in a list involves a slow linear search, whereas something with "set" in its name should provide fast membership testing.

Comment: Yup. `list` is nothing like a real multiset.

Comment: A `collections.Counter` is python's multiset.  It's even mention in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

Comment: @wim: That's what [_I_ said](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33102130/4014959) :)

Answer (score 5):

Transform your list to tuple(thus can be a item of set), then back to list.

```
>>> [list(i) for i in set([tuple(sorted(i)) for i in a])]
[[1, 2], [2], [2, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
```

Answer (score 4):

```
lst = [[1, 2], [2, 1], [3, 2, 2], [2], [2, 1, 3], [2, 2, 3]]
map(list, set(map(tuple, map(sorted, lst)))
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2], [2], [2, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
```

Comment: I don't know, kids these days, and their fancy schmancy functional programming. :)

Comment: LOL! I know that Guido would strongly object :-)

Comment: Dunno, I think you need some more `map` calls :-P.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
[list(i) for i in set(map(tuple, a))]
```

**EDIT:**
Assuming that `list` is already sorted. Thanks to @PM2RING to remind me.
If not, then add this line above

```
a = [sorted(i) for i in a]
```

Thanks again to @PM2RING: one liner

```
[list(i) for i in set(map(tuple, (sorted(i) for i in a)))]
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/h6sUMx)

Answer (score 2):

No Python, doesn't have a built-in multiset; the closest equivalent in the standard modules is [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), which is a type of dictionary. A Counter *may* be suitable for your needs, but it's hard to tell without more context.

Note that sets do *not* preserve order of addition. If you need to preserve the initial ordering of the lists, you can do what you want like this:

```
data = [[1, 2], [2, 1], [3, 2, 2], [2], [2, 1, 3], [2, 2, 3]]

a = set()
outlist = []
for s in data:
    t = tuple(sorted(s))
    if t not in a:
        a.add(t)
        outlist.append(list(t))

print(outlist)
```

**output**

```
[[1, 2], [2, 2, 3], [2], [1, 2, 3]]
```

If the number of input lists is fairly small you don't need the set (and the list<->tuple conversions), just test membership in `outlist`. However, that's not efficient for larger input lists since it performs a linear search on the list.

Comment: Check my answer for a more efficient de-dupe without that linear search

Answer (score 2):

Some of the solutions currently here are destroying ordering.  I'm not sure if that's important to you or not, but here is a version which preserves original ordering:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> A = [[1, 2], [2, 1], [3, 2, 2], [2], [2, 1, 3], [2, 2, 3]]
>>> [list(k) for k in OrderedDict.fromkeys(tuple(sorted(a)) for a in A)]
[[1, 2], [2, 2, 3], [2], [1, 2, 3]]
```